# Recovering samsung G5 after firmware flash?

Tags: recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-5, device-firmware

So, I purchased two Samsung Galaxy S5 phones from Amazon a while back. I have been playing around with the first after reflashing to a different firmware version - no issues arose. However, when I went to reflash the second phone with the *same* firmware image I used on the first the phone refuses to complete the boot sequence.

I am able to shell into the device during its boot sequence, but the phone never gets past the Samsung animation. Further inspection of their original packaging indicates that they may be from two different regions.

Now, is there a method for determining the correct firmware version (with respect to locality/baseband version) in order to recover the phone after the original firmware has been wiped? I have been trying various versions of Samsung G5 firmware, but all give the same unbootable result.

**tl;dr** Assuming no firmware is loaded and we have only the original bootloader, what are the recovery options? Even if I must first use some Samsung tool to recover to the latest version, this is fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Aren't there any device details printed on the device itself, maybe beneath the battery? You could check the model etc. there. Worst case, you need to contact Samsung with those numbers (or the IMEI if found), who should be able to give a clear answer based on that.

Comment: @Izzy, Oh, sorry. Of course! The model is SM-G900F, but I am not sure of the locality information required to download the correct firmware version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Samsung devices, but that specific detail definitely should help. Let me withdraw at this and let us hope someone more familiar with them jumps in with further ideas. Only thing I remember was Samsung is able to give you an exact answer on this if you tell them your IMEI (just in case nothing else helps). Good luck!

Comment: [Samsung Firmware archive](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=SM-G900f) See the packaging box of second phone to know about the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wiping the cache from bootloader menu .

or this

https://www.androidcentral.com/10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know this is a starting point to flash twrp or a custom rom using the Android Debug Bridge ADB

Look for a utube how to install ADB and fastboot for your pc . Then when u have adb command window open connect usb to device & use
1. The adb devices command which is "adb devices"

do this first before down loading any of the sdk package as you need to know if your pc can recognize your device.

you could also use somthing like this for the type of device you have this only works for samsung but there are others for different manufactures

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjz65GBkaneAhWlhKYKHaTHBuQQwqsBMAN6BAgDEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJv538rOL5p0&usg=AOvVaw3bIUhWGgbgikQiD3eBUfG1

hope this points you in right direction

Comment: This was a while ago now, but I think clearing the cache solved the problem.